# An algorithm for getting the position index

Tags: algorithms, search

Consider these two equation.

$$
m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4 = M_m\\
|m_1|+|m_2|+|m_3|+|m_4| = N_m
$$

where $\{m_i,M_m,N_m\}\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Given the value of $(N_m,M_m)$ we can find the different solutions for $(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4)$. The solutions are ordered in a particular way which is best explained by giving a few examples.

For e.g. with $(N_m = 2 ,M_m = 2)$ the solutions are

```
{{0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0}}
```

For e.g. with $(N_m = 2 ,M_m = -2)$ the solutions are

```
{{0, 0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, -2, 0}, {0, 0, -1, -1}, {0, -2, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 0}, {-2, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, -1,  0}, {-1, -1, 0, 0}}
```

For e.g. with $(N_m = 3 ,M_m = -1)$ the solutions are

```
{{0, 0, 1, -2}, {0, 1, 0, -2}, {1, 0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, -2, 1}, {0, 1, -2, 0}, {1, 0, -2, 0}, {0, 1, -1, -1}, {1, 0, -1, -1}, {0, -2, 0,1}, {0, -2, 1, 0}, {1, -2, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, 0}, {-2, 0, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 1, 0}, {-2, 1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, -1,  1}, {-1, 1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, -1, 1, 0}}
```

---

**Now what I would like is to find an efficient algorithm that can 
returns the position for a given set of $(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4)$.**

So for e.g given $\{m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4\} = \{0, 0, 1, 1\}$ the algorithm should return the number 2 since the solutions is in the second position (see e.g. 1 above).

Likewise

$\{0, 0, -1, -1\}$ returns 3

$\{-1, -1, 1, 0\}$ returns 24.

Note that I don't want to generate all the solutions for finding the position.
I have shown the solution just to show the ordering specially for negative input.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

This question was initially asked at `mathematica.stackexchange`.

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188495/find-position-without-iterating) is the link to that question

Comment: "The solutions are ordered in a particular way." That particular way is called [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).  $(a_1,a_2, \cdots, a_n)\prec(b_1,b_2, \cdots, b_n)$ if $a_i<b_i$ for the first $i$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ differ.

Comment: Do you have an algorithm when $N_m=M_m$?

Comment: Please see this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187670/find-permutation-index).

The accepted answer to that question works for the case `Nm = Mm`.  It uses the `Pochhammer` function.

Comment: I can't conclude a rule of ordering from your examples...

Comment: @xskxzr Do you understand the ordering for positive input in my e.g 1 for $N_m = M_m=2$.
It is such that the highest number starts from the right and moves towards the left. There is a definetly a pattern involved. It is left justified in some sense.
For negative input it is sorted by the negative sign .